# Where can I find mbp logic board compatibility information?

Tags: hardware, compatibility, logicboard, motherboard

I have an mbp late 2015 model and I want to do a DIY upgrade to the maximum compatible logic board, but I can't seem to google up any reliable information, and it turns out that as bizarre as it is, the board's port etc can be compatible from 2013 to 2014, but completely different in 2015, then completely different again in 2016? Which complicate things even more.

Where can I look up a chart or a list or in my case specifically, a late 2015 A1502?

So my question is where can I find information regarding the compatibility and you can answer by either giving me such information, a link, or tell me what is the maximum compatible logic board model for my machine, which is A1502 late 2015.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: A1502 is 13" Early 2015. What makes you think any other logic board might work?

Comment: Hi, I may have got it mixed up... So... only other 2015 1502 boards will work? This is exclusive to A1502 or to all other mbps? The other user made it sound like this is the common theme.

Comment: It certainly is a common theme.

Answer (score 1):

I am going to make the bold statement that there is no other logic board which will fit in or work with your MBP.

Look at the [iFixit](https://www.ifixit.com/Device/MacBook_Pro_13%22_Retina_Display) teardowns, logic board replacements and logic board purchases.

You will see that later logic boards are a different shape to yours, let alone having different connectors and functionality. The only choice in logic boards is their CPU and RAM. See the logic boards here [iFixit 13" 2015 MBP](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/MacBook+Pro+13-Inch+Retina+Display+Early+2015+Logic+Board+Replacement/45134)

Comment: Apple has been known to change the location of  screw stand-off holes so even a logic board that is dimensionally  compatible with different cases can only be fastened to the case it was "designed" for.

Comment: "The only choice in logic boards is their CPU and RAM" Hi, thanks for answering... but what else am I supposed to upgrade? 

Comment: Possibly the SSD (assuming you can find a compatible one). But I would not even think about an "upgrade" to a 2015 Mac unless it was not working. Basically you are not "supposed" to upgrade any Mac, with a few exceptions (e.g. Mac Pro, or RAM in 27" iMac).

Answer (score -1):

Macs are difficult to upgrade like that and if you can upgrade, your options are very limited to RAM and if lucky CPU. Some you can swap out the DVD drive for an SSD.  However, I did once see a really cool project where he turned his MBP into a tablet using a modified Wacom tablet digitizer. You can use a stylus and draw on the screen ect…

Comment: How does this answer the question?